# GridView - Set focus to specific cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've seen lots of posts out there for this question, however, they all suggest we use methods like:  `dgv.CurrentCell`   or  `dgv.Rows[row].Cells[cellno].Selected`.  Intellisense finds no such methods.  
I have a textbox in a gridview, where I use the OnTextChanged method.  Then, in my C# code, I update this quantity, then the grid refreshes automatically, and goes back to the top row, even though we've scrolled down a couple of pages.  I've also tried putting in the MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" in the 'Page' section of my .aspx page and that didn't seem to do anything.  We're on .Net Framework 4.0.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvOrderDetails" runat="server" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#FAFAFA" Width="940px" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="SortOrderDetails"
OnRowCommand="gvOrderDetails_RowCommand" EmptyDataText="No Data to Display"
DataKeyNames="STOREORDNUM" HeaderStyle-Height="22px" 
onselectedindexchanged="gvOrderDetails_SelectedIndexChanged">
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" /><EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF"/>
<FooterStyle BackColor="LightGray" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="Black" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="LightGray" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="Gray"/><PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB"  Height="22px"/>
<Columns>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="ITMCD" HeaderText="Item Code" SortExpression="ItemCode" >
     </asp:BoundField>
     ....                             
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order Qty" SortExpression="OrderQty" >
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="OrderQty" runat="server" Width="36" MaxLength="5" class="numberinput" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="buttonUpdateQty_Click" Text='<%# Bind("ORDERQTY") %>' ></asp:TextBox>                                   
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>                        
 </asp:GridView>
```

In the code behind, I've tried these two things:

```
gvOrderDetails.Rows[row.RowIndex].FindControl("OrderQty").Focus();
gvOrderDetails.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[7].Controls[0].Focus();
```

Comment: You are referring to a `GridView` control, not a `DataGridView` control.  The former is for `ASP.Net` pages and has a different set of properties.  I'm not an expert in ASP.Net but I think you need `gv.Rows[i].Cells[i].Controls[0].Focus()`

Comment: Thanks for the incredible response time (didn't expect that), but I just now tried that and it didn't seem to help.  What does the .Controls[0] mean?  In other words, what should I put there or is zero always correct?

Comment: That is the control inside the cell.  You didn't post your markup for the GridView and none of your code so it's hard for me to tell you.  I think you can use the control's name.

Comment: I have to leave work now and I may not get back to this until tomorrow, but [MSDN has pretty good documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s019wc0.aspx)  Also try googling "Focus Cell in ASP.Net GridView" - That should get you on the right track.

Comment: @Craig: try to cast the cell into `TextBox` and then call the `Focus()` check my answer below.

Comment: give that cell a class and in jquery  $('.YourClassName').focus();

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Panky:  Sorry, not a jquery expert.  In jQuery, how would I give that cell a class, and then where would I put the $('.YourClasName').focus(); code?

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the required cotrol cell into `Textbox` control and then call the `Focus()` method on it.

Try This:

```
TextBox txtOrderQty = (TextBox) gvOrderDetails.Rows[row.RowIndex].FindControl("OrderQty");
txtOrderQty.Focus();
```

Comment: I tried that, but no change.  At the top of my buttonUpdateQty_Click method, I already have the following code:  TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)tb.NamingContainer;  string itemCode = gvOrderDetails.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text;  And so I've also tried:  tb.Focus();

Answer (score 0):

Add a handler to SelectedindexChange Event of your grid view

```
Gridview1.SelectedRow.Focus();
```